# Laravel sub query not removing results when using a nested with

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a 'user' table that has a pivot table for services that a user offers:

```
// App\User
public function services()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ServiceUser');
}
```

On the ServiceUser model I then have another relationship to get the service information:

```
public function service() 
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Service', 'id');
}
```

When fetching a team (using Laravel Spark) the query I am using is:

```
Team::with('users')->withUserCustomerServices()->where('id', $teamId)->first();
```

The scope for this query is in the Team model:

```
public function scopeWithCustomerServices($query)
{
    $query = $query;
    $query->with('users.services');
    $query->with(['users.services.service' => function($q) {
        $q->where('visible_to_customers', 1);
    }]);
    return $query;
}
```

When outputting (using Vue.js):

```
{{ user.services.length }}
```

I get (in this example) 6 results returned. However, one of the services has a database field 'visible_to_customers' set to 0.

Initially I thought my query would work as expected and only return 5 services however it actually still returns them all, but doesn't return the relationship (service) if the field is 0.

How can I can I only return the pivot table result where the relationship has a certain field value?

**EDIT**

I have updated the query to use a whereHas on the first nested relation:

```
$query->with(['users.services' => function($q) {
    $q->whereHas('service', function($q) {
        $q->where('visible_to_customers', 1);
    });
}]);
```

This works great, only returns the pivot table rows where the services table has a field value of 1 for visible_to_customers.

However, that doesn't fetch the related row itself.

If I then chain on:

```
$query->with(['users.services' => function($q) {
    $q->whereHas('service', function($q) {
        $q->where('visible_to_customers', 1);
    });
}]);

$query->with(['users.services.service' => function($q) {
    $q->where('visible_to_customers', 1);
}]);
```

It remains the same issue where it fetch all of the rows but then only the related rows where the field is 1.

Comment: You need to use whereHas()

Comment: @R.K.Saini Yeah I just implemented that but running into another issue, ill update the question in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this issue by using a where has on the first relationship that is the pivot:

```
$query->with(['users.services' => function($q) {
    $q->whereHas('service', function($q) {
        $q->where('visible_to_customers', 1);
    })->with('service');
}]);
```

I then appended the ->with('service') to the end of the chain.